# Display specific part of tiff image using rasterio without having to load the entire file

Tags: python, tiff, rasterio

I have a large tiff file (around 2GB) containing a map. I have been able to successfully read the data and even display it using the following python code:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

with rasterio.open("image.tif") as img:
    show(img)
    data = img.read()
```

This works just fine. However, I need to be able to display specific parts of this map without having to load the entire file into memory (as it takes up too much of the RAM and is not doable on many other PCs). I tried using the Window class of rasterio in order to that, but when I tried to display the map the outcome was different from how the full map is displayed (as if it caused data loss):

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.windows import Window

with rasterio.open("image.tif") as img:
    data = img.read(window=Window(0, 0, 100000, 100000))
    show(data)
```

So my question is, how can I display a part of the map without having to load into memory the entire file, while also making it look as if it had been cropped from the full map image?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the outcome was different? I assume the coordinates, but also something else, like color?

Comment: @mihi both. first, it showed all the map while the width and height were less than the actual width and height. Also, this is a topographic map. when I displayed it fully it looked great, but when I tried to display a part of it it showed in yellow and purple and the heights weren't clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that it displays nicely in the first case, but not in the second, is that in the first case you pass an instance of `rasterio.DatasetReader` to `show` (`show(img)`), but in the second case you pass in a numpy array (`show(data)`). The `DatasetReader` contains additional information, in particular an affine transformation and color interpretation, which `show` uses.

The additional things `show` does in the first case (for RGB data) can be recreated for the windowed case like so:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import ColorInterp
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.windows import Window

with rasterio.open("image.tif") as img:
    window = Window(0, 0, 100000, 100000)

    # Lookup table for the color space in the source file
    source_colorinterp = dict(zip(img.colorinterp, img.indexes))

    # Read the image in the proper order so the numpy array will have the colors in the
    # order expected by matplotlib (RGB)
    rgb_indexes = [
        source_colorinterp[ci]
        for ci in (ColorInterp.red, ColorInterp.green, ColorInterp.blue)
    ]
    data = img.read(rgb_indexes, window=window)

    # Also pass in the affine transform corresponding to the window in order to
    # display the correct coordinates and possibly orientation
    show(data, transform=img.window_transform(window))
```

(I figured out what `show` does by looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/5e3fa33943fad02c1892c88ed1efe4e9b345f54e/rasterio/plot.py#L97-L109))

---

In case of data with a single channel, the underlying matplotlib library used for plotting scales the color range based on the min and max value of the data. To get exactly the same colors as before, you'll need to know the min and max of the whole image, or some values that come reasonably close.

Then you can explicitly tell matplotlib's `imshow` how to scale:

```
with rasterio.open("image.tif") as img:
    window = Window(0, 0, 100000, 100000)
    data = img.read(window=window, masked=True)

    # adjust these
    value_min = 0
    value_max = 255

    show(data, transform=img.window_transform(window), vmin=value_min, vmax=value_max)
```

Additional kwargs (like `vmin` and `vmax` here) will be passed on to `matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow`, as documented [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.plot.html#rasterio.plot.show).
From the matplotlib [documenation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow):

> vmin, vmax: float, optional
> When using scalar data and no explicit norm, vmin and vmax define the data range that the colormap covers. By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data. It is deprecated to use vmin/vmax when norm is given. When using RGB(A) data, parameters vmin/vmax are ignored.

That way you could also change the colormap it uses etc.

Comment: it doesn't have RGB channels though... just gray. this is what I get when I print the source_colorinterp dict:```{<ColorInterp.gray: 1>: 1}```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I've added some details for the single channel case as well. Without some actual data I'm not a 100% sure though. I hope it still helps :)